# Serialize `Nothing?` property via Jackson

Tags: kotlin, jackson

I want to serialize `FAIL` object via Jackson:

```kotlin
interface OptionalResult<out ResultType : Any> {

    val data: ResultType?

    object FAIL : OptionalResult<Nothing> {

        override val data: Nothing? = null
    }
}
```

What I get is `{}` but I expect to receive `{"data": null}`.

How can I fix my object?

By the way, the following object is serialized properly:

```kotlin
object FAIL : OptionalResult<Int> {

    override val data: Int? = null
}
```

Comment: Annotating `FAIL` object with `@JsonSerialize(using = MyCustomSerializer::class)` works! However, that requires 9 extra lines of code. Are there any other variants, for example, annotate `data` somehow?

Comment: It seems that now there is no way to make it more concise. Example of a custom serializer can be found here: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/issues/314

Answer (score 1):

Technical problem is that Jackson determines that indicator that would normally indicate existence of a property (public or annotated setter) will be filtered out, as getter is seen as `public void getData()` that returns nothing.
Filtering is done at low level processing, along with removal of static methods, methods that are neither annotated nor follow naming convention and so on.

It might be possible to improve upon this detection since there is actual difference between `void` and `Void` (similar to primitive/Wrapper difference). 
But this is the first time such usage has been reported.

One thing that you could try which may (or might not) help: add `@JsonProperty` for `val data`. It could help if filtering is only done for non-annotated accessors.